# Error during compile m4/glib

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, m4

I have some problems to compile `glib`. It seems as if `m4` not more up to date. I get this error:

```
In file included from clean-temp.h:22:0,
             from clean-temp.c:23:
./stdio.h:477:1: error: 'gets' undeclared here (not in a function)
```

So i get this error when i compile glib:

```
WARNING: 'automake-1.13' is probably too old.
     You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
     'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
     The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
     <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
     It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
     <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
     <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
     <http://www.perl.org/>
```

`Perl`, `Autoconf` and `Automake 1.14` are successful compiled.
Therefore, I conclude that the problem lies with m4.